# I'm having problems making particles from Unity's particle system to fill a shader/material when they collide with a collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am pretty new at video game development and I'm having problems making particles fall from a jar and fill a cup with water when they hit the collider. I'm not the best at making codes so I use most GPT to help me build this stuff and make adjustments along the way.

Sometimes I hit a wall like this and don't know how to proceed. I already searched online for answers and found nothing to help. So I decided to come here and asked for help from you all, any ideas? I will post the scripts that I'm using so you can see them.

I was only able to do It partially. When the particles collide with any collider they will automatically fill the cup shader/material. And I don't want this. I want to make the particles only fill the cup when they collide with the right collider that is set to "is trigger". This first code is the one that I'm using to fill the cup.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WCopoController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material material;
    public float speed = 1.0f;
    public float fillAmount = 0.5f; // Adicione uma variável para controlar a quantidade de preenchimento
    public ParticleSystem targetParticleSystem; // Adicione uma variável para armazenar o sistema de partículas alvo

    void Update()
    {
        material.SetFloat("_Fill", fillAmount); // Defina o valor do parâmetro "_Fill" para a quantidade de preenchimento desejada
    }

    void OnParticleCollision(GameObject other)
    {
        // Verifique se o objeto de colisão é o sistema de partículas alvo
        if (other.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>() == targetParticleSystem)
        {
            // Aumente a quantidade de preenchimento quando as partículas colidirem com o objeto alvo
            fillAmount += 0.1f;

            // Exiba uma mensagem no console para avisar que houve uma colisão
            Debug.Log("Colisão detectada!");
        }
    }

   public void SetTargetParticleSystem(ParticleSystem newTargetParticleSystem)
    {
        targetParticleSystem = newTargetParticleSystem;
    }
}
```

And this second one I'm using this to manage the score of the game in general. I'm making a game to help people to recover their hand and arm movements in a less boring way. I'm using Ultraleap to move the objects with my hands. The objective is to take the right object that will spawn randomly in front of the player and put it in the right collider to make points. The idea here is that I want to make the object tag in "correctTag" to only remove or add points when the cup is filled properly. Don't know if you all can help if this one but it's worth a shot.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScoreTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LogicManager logicManager;
    public int score = 0;
    public string correctTag;
    public string correctTag2;
    public string correctTag3;
    public string wrongTag1;
    public string wrongTag2;
    public string wrongTag3;
    public GameObject objectPrefab;
    public GameObject objectPrefab1;
    public GameObject objectPrefab2;
    public GameObject objectPrefab3;

    private bool objectDestroyed = false;
    public Animator animator;
    public Animator animator2;

    // Adicionando referências para os clipes de áudio e o componente AudioSource
    public AudioClip positiveSound;
    public AudioClip negativeSound;
    private AudioSource audioSource;

    // Adicionando uma referência pública para o componente ParticleSystem
    public ParticleSystem particleSystem;
    public ParticleSystem particleSystem2;

    // Adicionando uma referência pública para o componente Slider
    public Slider slider;
    public Slider slider2;



    void Start()
    {
        int handLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Maos");
        int colliderLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Collider");

        Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision(handLayer, colliderLayer);

        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (!objectDestroyed)
        {
            // Adicionando uma verificação para a tag do objeto gerado
            if (other.gameObject.CompareTag(correctTag) && other.gameObject.tag == FindObjectOfType<TrocadorObjetos>().currentObject.tag)
            {
                score++;
                Debug.Log("Score: " + score);
                Destroy(other.gameObject);

                logicManager.addScore();
                animator.SetTrigger("Scored");

                // Ativando o spawner de partículas
                particleSystem.Play();

                // Desativando o spawner de partículas após um segundo
                Invoke("StopParticleSystem", 1.0f);

                audioSource.PlayOneShot(positiveSound);

                // Adicionando uma chamada para o método GenerateObject() do script ObjectGenerator
                FindObjectOfType<TrocadorObjetos>().GenerateObject();
            }
            else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag(correctTag2))
            {
                slider.gameObject.SetActive(true); // Reative o objeto do slider
                slider.value += 0.1f; // Aumente o valor do slider em 0.1

                if (slider.value >= slider.maxValue)
                {
                    score++;
                    Debug.Log("Score: " + score);
                    Destroy(other.gameObject);

                    logicManager.addScore();
                    animator2.SetTrigger("Acertou");

                    // Ativando o spawner de partículas
                    particleSystem.Play();

                    // Desativando o spawner de partículas após um segundo
                    Invoke("StopParticleSystem", 1.0f);

                    audioSource.PlayOneShot(positiveSound);

                    // Adicionando uma chamada para o método GenerateObject() do script ObjectGenerator
                    FindObjectOfType<TrocadorObjetos>().GenerateObject();

                    slider.gameObject.SetActive(false); // Desative o objeto do slider
                    slider.value = 0; // Reinicie o valor do slider para zero
                    
                }
            }
            else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag(correctTag3))
            {
                slider2.gameObject.SetActive(true); // Reative o objeto do slider
                slider2.value += 0.1f; // Aumente o valor do slider em 0.1

                if (slider2.value >= slider2.maxValue)
                {
                    score++;
                    Debug.Log("Score: " + score);
                    Destroy(other.gameObject);

                    logicManager.addScore();
                    animator2.SetTrigger("Acertou");

                    // Ativando o spawner de partículas
                    particleSystem.Play();

                    // Desativando o spawner de partículas após um segundo
                    Invoke("StopParticleSystem", 1.0f);

                    audioSource.PlayOneShot(positiveSound);

                    // Adicionando uma chamada para o método GenerateObject() do script ObjectGenerator
                    FindObjectOfType<TrocadorObjetos>().GenerateObject();

                    slider2.gameObject.SetActive(false); // Desative o objeto do slider
                    slider2.value = 0; // Reinicie o valor do slider para zero
                }
            }
            else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag(wrongTag1))
            {
                score--;
                Debug.Log("Score: " + score);
                Destroy(other.gameObject);

                logicManager.loseScore();
                animator2.SetTrigger("Errou");

                // Ativando o spawner de partículas
                particleSystem2.Play();

                // Desativando o spawner de partículas após um segundo
                Invoke("StopParticleSystem2", 1.0f);

                audioSource.PlayOneShot(negativeSound);

                // Adicionando uma chamada para o método GenerateObject() do script ObjectGenerator
                FindObjectOfType<TrocadorObjetos>().GenerateObject();

                slider.gameObject.SetActive(false); // Desative o objeto do slider
                slider.value = 0; // Reinicie o valor do slider para zero
                slider2.gameObject.SetActive(false); // Desative o objeto do slider
                slider2.value = 0; // Reinicie o valor do slider para zero

            }
            else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag(wrongTag2))
            {
                score--;
                Debug.Log("Score: " + score);
                Destroy(other.gameObject);

                logicManager.loseScore();

                animator2.SetTrigger("Errou");


                // Ativando o spawner de partículas
                particleSystem2.Play();

                // Desativando o spawner de partículas após um segundo
                Invoke("StopParticleSystem2", 1.0f);

                audioSource.PlayOneShot(negativeSound);

                // Adicionando uma chamada para o método GenerateObject() do script ObjectGenerator
                FindObjectOfType<TrocadorObjetos>().GenerateObject();

                slider.gameObject.SetActive(false); // Desative o objeto do slider
                slider.value = 0; // Reinicie o valor do slider para zero
                slider2.gameObject.SetActive(false); // Desative o objeto do slider
                slider2.value = 0; // Reinicie o valor do slider para zero

            }

            else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag(wrongTag3))
            {
                score--;
                Debug.Log("Score: " + score);
                Destroy(other.gameObject);

                logicManager.loseScore();

                animator2.SetTrigger("Errou");


                // Ativando o spawner de partículas
                particleSystem2.Play();

                // Desativando o spawner de partículas após um segundo
                Invoke("StopParticleSystem2", 1.0f);

                audioSource.PlayOneShot(negativeSound);

                // Adicionando uma chamada para o método GenerateObject() do script ObjectGenerator
                FindObjectOfType<TrocadorObjetos>().GenerateObject();

                slider.gameObject.SetActive(false); // Desative o objeto do slider
                slider.value = 0; // Reinicie o valor do slider para zero
                slider2.gameObject.SetActive(false); // Desative o objeto do slider
                slider2.value = 0; // Reinicie o valor do slider para zero

            }


        }


    }
    // Método para desativar o spawner de partículas
    void StopParticleSystem()
    {
        particleSystem.Stop();
    }

    void StopParticleSystem2()
    {
        particleSystem2.Stop();
    }
}
```

Ignore the portuguese words and comments in it.

I already tried searching for videos and other forums for solutions. But I found nothing as I already mentioned. As I also said I want to fill the cup shader/material if the "water" particles that came from the jar when they hit a specific collider in the cup. And if possible make the object with the tag in the "correctTag" slot in the inspector only get or lost points. When the particles had collide and filled the cup object.